# Is donating blood or being on the donor register haram?

Tags: halal-haram, sadaqah, human-body

I believed that giving blood and being on the donor register was doing a good act but my dad thinks this is haram. Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Your perspective would be more correct in compare with your respected father's view. In truth, donating blood can be considered as a great profitable act which can save the life of many individuals. But it can be counted not as an appropriate practice if it make you a remarkable harm. In other word, it can be considered as an impermissible practice if your donating blood made you a significant harm for your body. But in common form, and actually in majority of the times it can be counted as a helpful act and might be it does not made a remarkable harm for majority of people. **As a consequence**, it ought not to be seen as a negative issue.

And Allah knows best